# Handlebars js register helper for object

Tags: javascript, handlebars

Как в handlebarsjs зарегистрировать helper type object, чтобы его можно было использовать в шаблоне как {{ test.first }} и {{ test.second }}?

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('test', function () {

  var test = {
    first: 'First',
    second: 'Second'
  };

  return test;

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Чтобы добавить глобальные хелперы, можно функцию Handlebars обернуть:

```
function render (html, options) {

  options.user = { name: 'Name', surname: 'Surname' };

  return Handlebars.compile(html)(options);

};
```

Вызов функции:

```
var html = '{{ text }} – {{ user.name }}';
var options = {
  text: 'Hello'
};

render(html, options);
```

Результат:

```
Hello – Name.
```